# calling event programmatically

Tags: vb.net, events, arguments, call

I have a datagridview and i want to delete a row selecting the row, pressing "delete" button.
and clicking my button "cmdsave" to do so. works great.
However  the code below doesn't delete the record.
what arguments do i put in **cmdsave_Click(SENDER???, e???)**

```
     private Sub datagridview_UserDeletingRow(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewRowCancelEventArgs) Handles datagridvieuw.UserDeletingRow
    If MsgBox("are you sure?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "delete this record") = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then             
        cmdsave_Click(SENDER???, e???)
    Else
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub cmdsave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdsave.Click
    Me.myadapter1.Update(Me.dataset.mydatatable)
    end sub
```

Comment: i can not update my datatable while still in "datagridview_UserDeletingRow"

Comment: Why would you call an event handler? Move `Me.myadapter1.Update(Me.dataset.mydatatable)` to its own method, so you can call it from anywhere when needed.

Comment: I tried that too but I just figured out that it should in datagridview_UserDeletedRow instead of datagridview_UserDeletingRow.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the specific question you asked:

> what arguments do i put in cmdsave_Click(SENDER???, e???

Anything you like; you never make use of either of the variables so you can put anything at all and it won't matter

`Nothing` is probably simplest

-

As you have figured out, you only call one method in the save click anyway, so it's probably simplest to just call that same method in both places